# Getting undefined when someone leave the server

Tags: discord.js

I am trying not to get undefined
I am getting

```
[SERVER] undefined Has left.
```

My code is

```
client.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
console.log(chalk.magenta(`[SERVER] `) +
chalk.bold.white(`${member.username} Has left.`))
});
```

and is they a way to add the name of the server to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) doesn't have a `username` property.

You'll want to use [`member.displayName`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=displayName) or [`member.user.username`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=username) depending on if you want the nickname (if they have one) or just their actual username.

If you want the username with the discriminator (ie. `username#0000`) then you'll have to use [`member.user.tag`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag).

Comment: nope still getting undefined and somethings a error